# Eclipse(and adb.exe from sdk) doesn't detect my beaglebone black as running android device

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, beaglebone-black

I need some help for problem. I'm using Beaglebone Black and Android (JellyBean 4.2.2) with 3.8 kernel. BBB connected to window7 through USB which comes with BBB. When I boot the android on micro SD card, it works fine(I'm using 4DCAPE LCD screen) but I cannot find it as running android device. I turn on the USB debug mode.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using the Andrew Henderson's 3.8 Kernel + Android JB configuration. As I understand the adb as it is intend is not functional in this configuration. Nikolay Elenkov in is blog has the following work around. Following is a direct word to word copy from the his blog

Configure FunctionFS support in the kernel

```
(CONFIG_USB_FUNCTIONFS=y):

Device Drivers -> USB Support -> 
     USB Gadget Support -> USB Gadget Driver -> Function Filesystem
```

Modify the boot parameters in uEnv.txt to set the vendor and product IDs, as well as the device serial number
g_ffs.idVendor=0x18d1 g_ffs.idProduct=0x4e26 g_ffs.iSerialNumber=
Setup the FunctionFS directory and mount it in your init.am335xevm.usb.rc file:

```
mkdir /dev/usb-ffs 0770 shell shell
mkdir /dev/usb-ffs/adb 0770 shell shell
mount functionfs adb /dev/usb-ffs/adb uid=2000,gid=2000
```

on fs

Delete all lines referencing /sys/class/android_usb/android0/*. (Those nodes are created by the native Android gadget driver and are not available when using FunctionFS.)

Please review this blog for detail infomation

http://nelenkov.blogspot.be/2013/07/building-wireless-android-device.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference (please [edit] your question and do so). Otherwise your question ceases to be helpful in case the link dies.